# Move elements in a list one position backward without mutating the original list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, sequences

I want to write a function that moves the position of all elements in a list one position backwards (to the left). The only conditions are that the function should not mutate the original list, and it must return nothing. In essence, how do I go from the code I have created here:

```
def cycle(input_list):
   move = input_list
   move.append(move.pop(0))
```

...which moves every element one position backwards but mutates the original list, to one that does the same thing, but instead doesn't mutate the original list?

Comment: its not clear to me...you want to keep the original list as it is or not?

Comment: I want to return a list that contains all the elements of the input_list, except each element  is shifted one position backward.

For example:
def cycle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Would return:
[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

Comment: So why does your question say "it must return nothing"? That's a bit confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy task then, return a copy with the elements shifted:

```
def cycle(input_list):
    return input_list[1:] + input_list[:1]
```

Comment: It will raise error as `input_list[1:]` is a list and `input_list[0]` is an item. Plus you don't need to check for length just do `def cycle(input_list): return input_list[1:] + input_list[:1]`.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir, true :), I cant just tested it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a copy of input list, modify in and return the value from cycle function, i.e. like this:

```
  def cycle(input):
      if len(input) > 1:     # check for empty lists
          res = list(input)  # make actual copy of the list
          res.append(res.pop(0))
          return res
      else:
          return []
```

There's good post on copying lists in Python: [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Comment: this will crash on empty lists